# Lisener in Android

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

in a proyect I neet to implement a method in back ground to  send a data stored in SQLite if lost the conexion with a api in ASP .Net this api i have a method to send the infor in json with the library "Retrofit" also. the informatin include text and images in base64, any idea or method that I can use.
Thanks :D

Comment: `try{sendData}catch(AnyException e) {saveDataLocally}`

Comment: Ok, the function to send and storage in local is do, but I need tell o excecute a method to send in a background the records in SQLite like a cronjob of PHP o cron like SQL server, to the API.
Sorry

Comment: I was unable to get any sense from your comment. Could you make it match the English rules a little more?

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution in another page